# Notice: Undefined index: email usando POST en PHP

Tags: php, email

Estoy haciendo un formulario de envio de correo electronico, lo subí a un host para comprobar que funcionará y si envia correos electronicos, pero me muestra los siguientes errores:

Notice: Undefined index: name in /storage/ssd1/931/16193931/public_html/correo.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: email in /storage/ssd1/931/16193931/public_html/correo.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: asunto in /storage/ssd1/931/16193931/public_html/correo.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: mensaje in /storage/ssd1/931/16193931/public_html/correo.php on line 6

Este es el codigo que envia correos electronicos:

```
<?php
$destino = "jjsanru3@gmail.com";
$nombre = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$asunto = $_POST["asunto"];
$mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"];

$contenido = "Nombre: ". $nombre . "\nCorreo:" . $email . "\nAsunto: " . $asunto . "\nMensaje: " . $mensaje;
mail($destino, $asunto, $contenido);
```

y este es el fomulario de envio de correo electronico

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Tu
                                            nombre</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text"
                                                class="form-control
                                                input-form-contact"
                                                placeholder="Escribe tu nombre" name="name" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Tu
                                            Email</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="email"
                                                class="form-control
                                                input-form-contact"
                                                placeholder="Escribe tu Email" name="email" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Asunto</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text"
                                                class="form-control
                                                input-form-contact"
                                                placeholder="Asunto" name="asunto" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Tu
                                            mensaje</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <textarea class="form-control
                                                input-form-contact" rows="3"
                                                placeholder="Escribe tu
                                                mensaje" name="mensaje" required></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary
                                        pull-right" name="enviar">Enviar</button>
                                </form>
                            <?php
                            include("correo.php");
                            ?>
```

Comment: En tu form hace falta el action a donde deben viajar los datos del mismo, como eso no esta presente por eso los errores

Answer (score 3):

Encierra todo tu código en

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

}
```

O también

```
if(isset(POST["enviar"])){

}
```

Donde "enviar" hace referencia al "name" de tu botón "submit".

Y con eso , ya no te saltará ningún error.

Comment: Habría que aclararle que esto evitaría el error pero aún así los valores no le llegarían de todos modos

Comment: Claro, al menos que el formulario html se encuentre en la misma página que el código php,de esa manera no haría falta el atributo "action" porque se enviaría a la misma página.